# Dynamic App Cache Using iFrame

Tags: iframe, html5-appcache

I have simple html page and i am writing a app cache file for this using servlet. I am trying to link another page using iFrame to this page. The second page has its own cache. 
Both the pages work independently with their own cache. When i tries to access the second page cache Using iFrame from the first page, it works online and get the second page. But in offline, the iFrame does not take the second page from cache and always tries to make server call and fails with the error:

net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Is their any alternative for this ?